# how do I add 2 to my score every second, I'm new to Xcode btw

Tags: swift, xcode

Im making a clicker game as my first ever game and im working on making a few upgrades. The first upgrade is an auto clicker. I want it to add 2 to my variable money every second. I made a var called moneypersecond. I got it so moneypersecond is right and shows how much I should be getting per second but I just need to update my money every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer to achieve what you want.

1. Declare a variable Timer:

   `var timer: Timer?`
2. Start your auto-clicker (in viewDidLoad for example), by assigning a repeating timer that executes a function incrementMoney.

   ```
   timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(incrementMoney(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   ```
3. Here is your function incrementMoney:

   ```
   @objc func incrementMoney(_ timer: Timer) {
       moneyPerSecond += 2
       // You can set a limit here and increment your timer, if money reaches 5000 for example.
   }
   ```
4. Finally, when you are done, don't forget to invalidate your timer as follows:

   `timer?.invalidate()`